# Is there a way that I can use my "data," "values," and "rowNumber" constants from my "func startObservingDB()" in my "tableView" functions?

Tags: swift, scope

I know the issue is regarding scope; I just dont know if theres an easy fix I can do without changing my code much. but open to anything

```swift
    import UIKit
    import Firebase
    import FirebaseAuth
    import FirebaseFirestore

    class AdminViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, 
UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var custodianRunReportsTableView: UITableView!
    
    var dbRef: DatabaseReference!
    
    var data = [String]()



    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        startObservingDB()
        
        custodianRunReportsTableView.delegate = self
        custodianRunReportsTableView.dataSource = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    // Gets users' names from Cloud Firestore Database
    func startObservingDB() {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let namesDocumentRef = db.collection("Users").document("Names")
        
        namesDocumentRef.addSnapshotListener { DocumentSnapshot, error in
            guard let document = DocumentSnapshot else {
                print("Error fetching document: \(error!)")
                return
            }
            guard let data = document.data() else {
                print("Document data was empty.")
                return
            }
            let values = data.values
            let rowNumber = data.count
            
            print("Current data: \(data)")
            print("Current data has the values: \(values)")
            print("Current data totals \(data.count) items.")
            
        }
        
        

    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("You tapped me!")
    }
    
}

    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return rowNumber
    }
        
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = custodianRunReportsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = values[indexPath.row]
        print("Names in cell: \(values)")
        print("\(data)")
        
        return cell
    }
    
}
```

UPDATED CODE:

This is updated after an answer to the original post. The code no longer has the unresolved identified error; however, the table view does not display any cell text and is empty.

```
class AdminViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet var custodianRunReportsTableView: UITableView!

var valuesArray:[String] = []

var data:[String] = []

var namesDocumentRef:DocumentReference!







override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    startObservingDB()
    
    custodianRunReportsTableView.delegate = self
    custodianRunReportsTableView.dataSource = self
    
}

// Gets users' names from Cloud Firestore Database
func startObservingDB() {
    var namesDocumentRef:DocumentReference!
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    namesDocumentRef = db.collection("Users").document("Names")
    namesDocumentRef.addSnapshotListener { DocumentSnapshot, error in
        if error != nil{
            return
        }
        else {
            guard let snapshot = DocumentSnapshot, snapshot.exists else {return}
            guard let data = snapshot.data() else { return }
            self.valuesArray = Array(data.values) as! Array<String>
        }
    }
}
        

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("You tapped me!")
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return valuesArray.count
}
    
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = custodianRunReportsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    
    cell.textLabel?.text = valuesArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

}

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Can you clear that? What's the structure inside `data.values`? why you. need `data` to be saved? Please clarify the question. And also, show what are the fields inside `document("Names")`?

Comment: Oh yea, sorry; I’m ultimately trying to use some data from my firebase cloud firestore database as the text label for rows in my table view. I’m not quite sure what you mean by “structure inside data.values”; however, the data is just key-value pairs like “Name1: Robert Garcia” etc. So the data in data.values is just the values or for example, “Robert Garcia.”

Comment: The fields inside “Names” are just sequential “Name1,” “Name2,” “Name3,” and “Name4.” and their values are “Robert Garcia,” “Aggie Diaz,” “Martinna Garcia,” and “Jonathan Nava.”

Comment: All the prints work well; it prints out the correct data (the key-value pairs), values (the names), and number of values (4). I just need to reference those values and the count of those values in my table view so the table view can use that information to create the same number of rows as there names and display the names on the cell.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering, I fell asleep LOL

Comment: Okay got it. I am answering

Comment: also, i think var data and var dbRef were from a different attempt at making this code work; so i think u can disregard those. i’m not sure because idk if i’m missing it while i’m looking through the code. pretty sure tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables `data`,`values` and `rowCount` are inside closure so you can't just write `values[indexPath.row]` because you can't return from inside closure. Usually completionHandlers are used for this purpose, but in this scenario, you should put the `values` inside an array and then use inside the tableview. Let me show you how to do.

At the start of your viewController, declare a string array.

```
var valuesArray:[String] = []
```

Then, inside modify your `startObservingDB()` function

```
func startObservingDB() {
    var docRef:DocumentReference!
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    docRef = db.collection("Users").document("Names")
    docRef.addSnapshotListener { (docSnapshot, error) in
       if error != nil {
            return
           }
           else {
                   guard let snapshot = docSnapshot, snapshot.exists else {return}
                   guard let data = snapshot.data() else { return }
                    self.valuesArray = Array(data.values) as! Array<String>
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
       }
```

In `viewDidLoad` call this function

```
startObservingDB()
```

Then in `tableView` methods

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return ValuesArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  
    let cell = custodianRunReportsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
     cell.textLabel?.text = valuesArray[indexPath.row]
     return cell
}
```

Comment: Oh my goodness, thank you so much; trying right now!

Comment: Sure! Do let me know if you face any problem

Comment: okay, there are no longer "use of unresolved identifier" errors. However, when I run the app simulator, the table view is empty.

Comment: I just updated my original post to include my updated code after following your answer's suggestions.

Comment: @RobertGarcia, Oh okay Just add `tableView.reloadData()` in the end of `startObservingDB` and don't forget to call `startObservingDB` in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Ohmygosh, you're a genius, "reloadData()" made it work! I can't thank you enough. You made this so simple and so clear, especially for asking my first-ever question on stack overflow. You're a genius, man

Comment: Glad to help you brother!

Comment: sorry to bother you; I don’t know if you’ll see this. But i haven’t been able to find a solution to another problem I’m having with a tableview cell. If you find the time, the link to that question is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62770335/dealing-with-dynamic-cells-in-a-uitableview

Answer (score -1):

In your class `AdminViewController` you can reference properties defined outside of methods with `self` (in your example you have `dbRef` that you can reference like `self.dbRef` in methods).

So I suggest you make properties for data, value and rowNumber and change them in `startObservingDB` method rather than declare them. This way you will be able to reference them in tableView methods.

Comment: ahh, okay; “make properties” rather than declare them. What does “making a property” look like? Thanks for answering

Comment: just looked at some examples, i think that makes a lot of sense; thank you